# How to print a given date in C

Tags: c, date, scanf

I am very new to C programming. I was trying to use the `scanf` function to ask the user to enter a date and display it in the console. So wrote the following codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int date, month, year;
    printf("Please enter the date in the form of dd/mm/yyyy: ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &date, &month, &year);

    printf("the date you entered was:  %d-%d-%d\n", date, month, year);
    return 0;
}
```

But the output am getting is not in a proper format, for example, I type in "10-12-2016", but the result I get was "10-554502544-32766". Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"i type in "10-12-2016""* - which doesn't match your format string. The result of `scanf`, which you currently don't check, would have told you only one of your arguments was successfully parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` is a fairly kludgy tool. It expects the format to be exactly as you specified and if it isn't you get weird behaviour.

You either need to enter the text exactly as specified (dd/mm/yy, not dd-mm-yy) or change how you go about things.

Consider having `scanf()` scan in a string that you then lex yourself to get the values you want - you can be much more tolerant of variances in the input that way, as well as be more proof against someone trying to break your program by deliberately giving it invalid input.

Answer (score 2):

In your `scanf()`, you have this format - `%d/%d/%d` but you are giving the input as `10-12-2016`, so you are doing wrong!

Instead, you should give input as - `10/12/2016` and the `%d/%d/%d` part in `scanf()` will ignore the `/` part from the input.

> I type in 10-12-2016, but the result I get was 10-554502544-32766. Any idea guys?

Yes, when you are giving `10-12-2016` as input, `scanf()` assigning only `10` to `date` variable but no value to the other variables. Since the other two variables `month` and `year` is uninitialized, you are getting garbage value (554502544 and 32766) when you print the value of variable `month` and `year`.

One way to check this: Just initialize the variable and then take input.

```
int date = 0, month = 0, year = 0;
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &date, &month, &year);
```

Now, if you give `10-12-2016` as input, you will get `10-0-0` as output. Hopefully you can understand what is actually happening!

Comment: Alternatively, `"%d%*c%d%*c%d"`, which would accept *any* non-digit char separating the three integer values. Or `"%d%*[/-]%d%*[/-]%d"`, which would allow only `/` or `-` as numeric separators (which can still be mixed or matched). And as always, the result of `scanf` should be checked to ensure the expected arguments were all successfully populated.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wasi

Comment: @WhozCraig Sir, I Need To Talk To You Can We Have Chat ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the return value from `scanf` - [See the manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int date, month, year;
    printf("Please enter the date in the form of dd/mm/yyyy: ");
    if (scanf("%d/%d/%d", &date, &month, &year) == 3) { 
       printf("the date you entered was:  %d-%d-%d\n", date, month, year);
    } else {
       printf("You have made an error\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Ed, whats `if (scanf("%d/%d/%d", &date, &month, &year) == 3)` means?

Comment: Any idea about that 3 Ed?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int date, month, year;
    printf("Please enter the date in the form of dd press enter then enter mm then press enter then enter year then press enter.. ");
    scanf("%d", &date);
    scanf("%d", &month);
    scanf("%d", &year);
    printf("the date you entered was:  %d/%d/%d\n", date, month, year);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While a valid method, doesn't solve his problem or answer why he's having the issue.

Comment: that is simple solution by new user of c

Comment: He wants to be able to enter in the date as a single string, not having to hit enter after each portion of the date.

Comment: that entered format is string not date formate..that not specifi that gate formate..